# Excel: sum a column by comparing dates in one column with a date in one cell

Tags: excel

I have one column with dates, one column with values and one cell with date in excel. I want to see if the dates in the column is greater than the cell date if it is then sum up the values from another column

for eg. - 
sheet1 A:A has dates
Sheet1 B:B has numbers
Sheet 2 cell A has a date 02/02/2013

If cell A is greater than sheet1 A:A then sum Sheet 1 B:B in a seperate cell.

Thanks so much

Comment: In the future please give examples, maybe even a screen shot and an attempt of what you have done. It is hard to help with no data.

Comment: thanks seekingalpha, will do

Comment: did you try my suggestion? I noticed the given date is on a separate worksheet. If that is the case when typing the function you can always click to the date to pass in the value. Make sure you have the $ signs  in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill out another column and enter this formula:

```
=IF(A1>$C$1,B1,"")
```

and drag the formula down. What you will have in this new column is all the numbers of the dates that are greater then the date in cell C1.

You can then just sum up the column.

A bit hacky but it will do what you want.

NOTE: assuming that the given date is in cell C1. Could not tell from your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!A:A,">"&Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!B:B)
```

This `SUMIF` formula will sum up all the values in sheet 1 column B where the value in sheet 1 column A are greater than the value in sheet 2 cell A1.

Comment: Are you sure the date column has actual dates in it and not text?

Comment: @Hotvivid Please explain what 'it didn't work' means. Does that give you an error? Does that give you the wrong sum? Does that make your excel crash? So many possibilities out there and you need to be clearer if you want people to help you out.

Comment: hi it gave me zero. instead of the sum of values. have got those in the date format, but i am also thinking that it is the formatting issue. i will try again to play with the format and will let you know if i am successful. thanks